# When parsing a MongoDB object (using Mongoose), how come I can't get item elements?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

```
IndexedTweets.find(searchParameters, function(err, indexedTweetsResults) {
  var chunkSize, count, resultArray, size;
  if (err != null) {
    return console.log("Error!");
  } else {
    size = indexedTweetsResults.length;
    count = 0;
    chunkSize = 100;
    resultArray = [];
    indexedTweetsResults.forEach(function(tweet) {
      console.log(tweet.user);
    });
  }
});
```

That's my code. My result looks like:

```
{ text: 'stuff',
  user: 
   { display_name: '...',
     screen_name: '...'},
}
```

So why can't I get `tweet.user`? It just returns `undefined`.

Comment: it looks like the result you are showing is actually console.log(tweet); unless I'm mistaken. Otherwise, perhaps tweet.user.user. Also, where are you "getting" it? In the same forEach or somewhere else?

Comment: Correct - but When I get `tweet.user`, it shows as undefined. I'm getting it as a result of the find and then forEach'd

Comment: what happens when you do tweet.user.display_name? Is it possible user is undefined for some of the tweet objects, for whatever reason, but not for others?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting back a string of JSON from mongo, you'll need to call JSON.parse().  If that's not the case then you should provide more code because it's not clear what the issue is.